# Recurrence relation for the sequence of numbers $3, 15, 57, 195, ...$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Is there any systematic way to calculate a recurrence relation for a sequence of numbers?

For instance, I am trying to solve the recurrence relation for $3, 15, 57, 195, ...$ but cannot seem to define an acceptable recurrence relation.

The context for this question is I have to find the recurrance relation for the number of n digit ternary sequences (i.e. strings of  $0, 1$ and $2$) that contain at least two consecutive digits that are the same.

I cannot find a way to define this so I have "manually" calculated the ways this would work out to for $n = 2, 3, 4$ and $5$ which are the four sequences provided above.

Comment: If you just want the answer, https://oeis.org/A210448 says it's $3(3^n-2^n)$.  (Possible offset by $1$ from the definition given at OEIS.)

Comment: @BrianTung $\displaystyle\left.11n^{3} -51n^{2} + 88n - 45\,\right\vert_{\ n\ =\ 1,2,3,\ldots}\quad$ is fine too$\ldots$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is at par with *guess the next number* -questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $a_{i}$ as the number of $i$  - digit ternary numbers with at least one consecutive repeating number.

For any $n$ - digits ternary numbers ($3^{n}$ of them), we can attach a number equal to the last digit at the end and get $n+1$ - digits ternary number with at least one consecutive repeating number.

In addition, for any $n$ - digits ternary numbers with at least one consecutive repeating number ($a_{n}$ of them), we can attach a number different from the last digit ($2$ possibilities) at the end and get $n+1$ - digits ternary number with at least one consecutive repeating number.

$a_{n+1}=3^{n}+2\cdot a_{n}$

Answer (score 3):

One can easily calculate an explicit formula for the number of such sequences. The number of $n$-digit sequences with *no* pair of consecutive digits the same is $3\cdot 2^{n-1}$ (the first digit can be anything; subsequent digits cannot be the same as the previous one).

So the number of $n$-digit sequences with at least one pair of consecutive digits the same is $3^n-3\cdot 2^{n-1} = 3(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1})$.

If you want, you can work backwards from this to derive a recursion. Let $a_n$ be the number of such sequences, so that $a_n = 3(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1})$. Then
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-2a_n &= 3^{n+1}-3\cdot 2^n - 6(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1})\\
&= 3^{n+1}-3\cdot 2^n - 2\cdot 3^n+3\cdot 2^n \\
&= 3^{n+1}-2\cdot 3^n \\
&= 3^n.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'd say this answers the question.  Not everything is best solved with a recurrence, after all!

Answer (score 2):

It’s actually possible to guess a recurrence just from the values of $a_2,a_3,a_4$, and $a_5$ calculated by hand: I did it after reading just the title of the question (and adjusting slightly when I finally read the question and learned the indexing). Of course one must then either prove that the recurrence is correct or solve it and prove that the closed form is correct.

The numbers $3,15,57$, and $195$ seem to be growing very roughly exponentially, and each is a little more than $3$ times the previous number. In fact, a little quick arithmetic reveals that $15=3\cdot3+6$, $57=3\cdot15+12$, and $195=3\cdot57+24$, and the numbers $6,12$, and $24$ are encouragingly systematic: we might venture the guess that $a_n=3a_{n-1}+3\cdot2^{n-2}$. This recurrence is easily solved by unwinding:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}+3\cdot2^{n-2}\\
&=3(3a_{n-2}+3\cdot2^{n-3})+3\cdot2^{n-2}\\
&=3^2a_{n-2}+3^2\cdot2^{n-3}+3\cdot2^{n-2}\\
&=3^2(3a_{n-3}+3\cdot2^{n-4})+3^2\cdot2^{n-3}+3\cdot2^{n-2}\\
&=3^3a_{n-3}+3^3\cdot2^{n-4}+3^2\cdot2^{n-3}+3\cdot2^{n-2}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=3^ka_{n-k}+\sum_{i=1}^k3^i\cdot2^{n-1-i}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^i\cdot2^{n-1-i}\qquad(\text{since }a_1=0)\\
&=2^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac32\right)^i\\
&=2^{n-1}\frac{\left(\frac32\right)^n-\frac32}{\frac32-1}\\
&=3^n-3\cdot2^{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

Since $3^n$ is the number of ternary sequences of length $n$, it makes sense at this point to consider whether $3\cdot2^{n-1}$ can easily be interpreted as the number of unwanted sequences of length $n$, i.e., those that do not have at least two consecutive identical digits. And that turns out to be the case: there are $3$ ways to pick the first digit, and after that there are always $2$ choices for the next digit if each digit is to be different from its predecessor.

I really do think that it would be easier just to invest a bit of thought first and come up with this result directly, as in **rogerl**’s answer: subtracting the number of ‘bad’ sequences from the number of possible sequences is one of the obvious approaches that should be tried early on. But the best of us have the occasional blind spot, and this *is* a possible approach if one is accustomed to playing with numbers and nothing better comes to mind.